# get words from file name, and zip and store as variables

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I have a directory of .pdf files with two words; FIRST and LAST name as the file name, AND the zipcode; *i.e.* '`CAPTAIN RON 11222.pdf`'

I would like to, per file, get the words (`NAME`) and numbers (`ZIP`) from each file in the directory.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
```

As I will later use each, to find what actual name to use to rename with. *i.e.* below is what I'm trying to accomplish logically (full context; but I think above is the problem part):

```
for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):

        data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        header = df.iloc[0]

        row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index.min()
        row_numberd12 = df[df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()

    if row_numberd1 == row_numberd12: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF1
        rowMatched = row_numberd1
        print("Match Found")
        print(rowMatched)

        MemberID = df['ID'][rowMatched]
        MemberI = str(MemberID)

        with open("./pdfs/ID/" + MemberI + ".pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
             output.write(outputStream)
```

..........

**I am not trying to store these into a dataframe. I want to search an excel files (dataframe) to find where the name and zip are on the same row. Then use that row number to get a columns value as the new name.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
         First_Name, Last_Name, Zip = filename.replace(".pdf",'').split()
         Name = First_Name+Last_Name
```

And then you can use Name and Zip variables as intended

Comment: Simply declaring 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', and 'Zip' will automatically grab it from each file's name?

Comment: It is not simply declaring @CaptainRon but splitting as filename in itself is a string

Comment: This seems to answer the first part of my question; now the second part is here: How to rename with values from DF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383038/rename-files-from-where-rows-meet-in-df

Answer (score 2):

I think the `glob` module is a good use case for for this.

I'm assuming your data will follow the standard pattern, first name, last name and zip, split by white space.

```
import os
import glob

path = r'\your\dir'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path) + '\*.pdf') 

pdfs = [os.path.basename(f) for f in files] # pass the names into a list.

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'PDF' : pdfs}) # make a data frame with the file name. 
df['PDF'] = df['PDF'].str.replace('.pdf','') # remove the PDF element, 


# assign your variables to columns 

df['First Name'] = df['PDF'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[0]
df['Last Name'] = df['PDF'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[1]
df['Zip'] = df['PDF'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not trying to store these into a dataframe. I want to search an excel files (dataframe) to find where the name and zip are on the same row. Then use that row number to get a columns value as the new name.

Comment: can you show some sample of your excel dataframe ? also do you want to over-right the pdf name or make a copy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383038/rename-files-from-where-rows-meet-in-df